# Does Chromium not support SOCKS5H (with the "H" in the end)?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, chromium, socks, socks5

If I try to start Chromium or any Chromium-based browser with:

```
[...] --proxy-server="socks5h://blablabla"
```

Then it fails to load any page. However, it works if I do:

```
[...] --proxy-server="socks5://blablabla"
```

But SOCKS5H and SOCKS5 are slightly different in an important way. the "H" one doesn't leak your privacy by bypassing the proxy for DNS lookups, but this is not supported in Chromium?

The proxies I am trying are otherwise working (such as via cURL) and are indeed SOCKS5**H**.

I find not a word about this online, "surprisingly".

The error given is something like this:

> This site can’t be reached
> The webpage at https://ifconfig.co/json might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This convention originated in `curl` :
When `socks5` is used the domain name is resolved locally and the
resolved IP is passed to the proxy server.
This is usually undesirable, since it leaks DNS requests, defeating
some of the privacy of using proxy, etc.
`socks5h` caused curl to pass domain name to the SOCKS server verbatim
and let the server do the resolving.

Nowadays, most client programs do not resolve locally the domain name,
so the `socks5h` protocol has fallen into disuse.
For such clients, `socks5h` is the same as `socks5`, or in other words
all `socks5` are actually `socks5h`.

Evidently, Firefox is one such client.

Comment: But.. um... hmm. This both answers the question "kinda" but also confuses me further. I'm finding it hard to explain what is so confusing about this, but I don't understand why the non-"h" SOCKS5 protocol/mode ever existed in the first place.

Comment: This distinction came from curl, to distinguish between the two methods. This was an implementation decision by the developers of curl, that wasn't universally adopted. The protocol, in any case, is always the `socks5` protocol. Resolving DNS or not is secondary, because the `socks5` protocol accepts both a domain name or an IP address. It's not worth a real protocol name, since it's not a protocol, just a way to force curl to send the domain name and not the IP.

Comment: @harrymc This is awesome info. Any reference? Even the wikipedia article on socks5 does not provide enough info about `socks5h`.

Comment: @Oliver: I have done research for compiling this answer. There wasn't one comprehensive source that I found at that time, so I didn't incorporate any link into my answer.